# How can I fix my Python code?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

my program works until it gets the to "if" part, then it just stops working. any ideas?

```
import random
skill = str()
skill2 = str()
strength1 = str()
strength2 = str()
final = str()
strength_modifier = str()
skill_modifier = str()
dice = int()

strength1 = input("Please enter your strength level for character 1: ")
print(strength1)
skill1 = input("Please enter your skill level for character 2: ")
print(skill1)

strength2 = input("Please enter your strength level for character 2: ")
print(strength2)
skill2 = input("Please enter your strength level for skill 2: ")
print(skill2)

if strength1 > strength2:
    strength_modifier =(int(strength1)-int(strength2))
    print(strength_modifier)

if strength2 > strength1:
    strength_modifier = (int(strength2)-int(strength1))
    print(strength_modifier)

if skill1 > skill2:
    skill_modifier = (int(skill1)-int(skill2))
    print(skill_modifier)

if skill2 > skill1:
    skill_modifier = (int(skill2)-int(skill1))
    print(skill_modifier)
```

can somebody please just fix it and post it on here please:L

Comment: You will have to be more specific - what does this program do, what inputs do you accept, whether this is python3 vs 2.7 and so on.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: i need it to find out the difference between two numbers when it gets the the "if" bit, thats why when it gets to the "if" bit im trying to make it minus the smallest number from the biggest number beucase then ill get the differnce.

Comment: im a beginner so i dont understand complicated wording

Comment: With what values are you running your program?

Comment: im not sure sorry, im a beginner so i dont no much, if its any help they input the number they want?

Comment: Please remove every assignment at the top of your program, i.e. `skill = str()` and so on. They serve no purpose

Answer (score 8):

I guess the variables are actually strings and you tried to compare two strings with ">". Try cast string to int first.

Comment: `input()` [returns a string](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: `strength1 = int(input("Enter your input: "))`. The cast might be failed with an exception

Comment: That is a good idea for the additional benefit that they won't be casting to int all over the place later in the code (in all the if blocks).

Answer (score 0):

When you define you variables to str() you are assigning them to an empty string (try to run str() in the command shell or IDLE and see its return value).

Then, with your input() function you are re-defining the variables to some strings, and in the if statements you are comparing strings with those comparison operators! What it does, when comparing strings, is checking the first character of the string! so, a string starting with 'b' is greater than a string starting with 'a', and 'c' > 'b' > 'a' and so on and so forth.
When the string is a number, like this '1234412' it checks the absolute value of the first digit, so '1231432' > '2' would return False, since 2 is bigger than 1.

What you want to do is, when asking for input, say that the variable should be equal to the number that was written by the user. like this:

```
skill1 = int(input("Type your skill... :"))
```

But this may throw in an error if the user doesn't type a number, so you may want to catch the error, and still ask for valid input! Do it like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        skill1 = int(input("bla bla : "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Type in a NUMBER")
```

You may also want to join the if-statements that are working in pairs! You might do this in 2 ways: an Else statement, or an Elif statement... The Else statement executes if all the other If-Elif statements evaluated to False; An Elif statement executes if all the If-Elif statements above it, in the same block, evaluated to False!.

```
if #some condition#:
    #some code
elif #some condition#: <== Only executes if the one above didn't execute
    #some code
elif #some condition#: <== Only executes if the ones above didn't execute
    #some code
else: # executes only if none of the above statements evaluated True.
```

When using an If-Elif-Else block like this, you always know that one, and **only one** of the code parts will execute, because when one condition evaluates True, it enters that statement's indented code, and when it finishes it skips all of the other conditions! Code like this will work in the following way:

```
a = 10
if a < 20:
    print("Var 'a' is smaller than 20")
elif a < 30:
    print("Var 'a' is smaller than 30")
```

Although the a<30 is True, it will only call the first print, because when the interpreter enters the first if, it will automatically skip all the other elif's and the else statement.